# How to use new Android 2.0 Shrinker and set useProguard false?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I upgraded to Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5.  I'm using gradle tools 2.0.0-beta5.  On the Android dev blogspot site, there is a video explaining how to use the new Shrinker for debug builds (at 3:14)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_w6fodMGrA1_tsI3pqPbqa&v=xxx3Fn7EowU

I'm trying to build my project with the debug buildType as explained in the video:

```
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
    }
```

I'm getting a bunch of warnings and then this this error when building:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 'app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForMyAppNameGoesHereDebug'.
Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
```

With Proguard, I would add the appropriate -dontwarn necessary in the proguard project file.  Is there a Shrinker project file somewhere that I can add -dontwarn statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found some [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/built-in-shrinker) on this. Turns out it uses the same configuration files as Proguard. Here is the relevant part from the doc:

> The built-in shrinker can only remove dead code, it does not obfuscate or optimize. **It can be configured using the same files as ProGuard, but will ignore all flags related to obfuscation or optimization**. Unlike ProGuard, we support using the built-in shrinker together with Instant Run.

Also, here is a sample configuration for reference:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiled and installed APK.  Thanks!  Unfortunately there already is a problem with my proguard configuration.  Jackson is throwing a "no suitable constructor found" error.  But at least it's building now.

Comment: I saw some posts on SO regarding the Jackson issue before. At least you made it further than I did! I was excited to see that adding the -dontwarn flags got me past the `transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug` step. However that just led to a 64K method error which is strange since the project builds with the same Proguard rules when using Proguard.